# Difference between the descendant selector and the .find() method in jquery selectors

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I want to know whether there exists any differences between these two jquery codes:

```
$("div#intro .head")
```

and

```
$("div#intro").find(".head")
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As written, they both produce the same output, but the second one with `.find` requires first constructing a jQuery object for all elements matching `div#intro` first, so the first one is probably preferable (not to mention more concise).

That said, there are a number of things `.find` can do that the descendant selector cannot:

- Use a jQuery object as an argument

```js
const $greenSpans = $('span.green');

// ...
// later:

const found = $('div').find($greenSpans);
console.log(found.length, found[0]);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span class="green">1</span>
<div>
  <span class="green">2</span>
</div>
```

- Use an HTMLElement as an argument

```js
// not so useful, because you already have a reference to the element to change

const greenSpan = document.querySelectorAll('span.green')[1];

// ...
// later

const found = $('div').find(greenSpan);
console.log(found.length, found[0]);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span class="green">1</span>
<div>
  <span class="green">2</span>
</div>
```

- Operate on a jQuery object that has already been created

```js
const $div = $('div');

// ...
// later

const found = $div.find('span');;
console.log(found.length, found[0]);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span class="green">1</span>
<div>
  <span class="green">2</span>
</div>
```

Comment: Well, do you think the first one is more time effecient than the second one?

Comment: Yes - like I said in the answer, *the second one with `.find` requires first constructing a jQuery object for all elements matching `div#intro` first*, so it's less efficient.